# Export behaviors preferences in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to export my custom behaviors preferences in Xcode 5 to share them with others Macs?

[image: My custom behaviors settings]

Comment: Could you describe which behaviors you are trying to export?

Comment: I think he refers to the behavior tab in Xcode setting window.

Comment: Yes, I ´ve uploaded a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try export the plist `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` to other macs.